# Is it possible to use hget in ioredis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to use hget and hset in ioredis in my node script, I check the documentation, but can not find how to do it, Any idea how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: the ioredis doc page [link](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)

Comment: the solution is:

redisclient.hget(key,subkey,function(error,data){
  //...
});

Answer (score 6):

This has been answered in the comment, but for future search engine hits, here's a runnable example if you have installed ioredis with `npm i ioredis`.

ioredis version used: ioredis@3.2.2

```
const ioredis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new ioredis();

redis.hset('foo_key','foo_subkey', 'foo_value');

redis.hget('foo_key', 'foo_subkey').then(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});

redis.quit();
```